# Net Core on Docker for Windows SQL Server not working

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm creating a new empty ASP.NET Core 2.2 with Docker support enabled (Docker for Windows).

When I run it on Docker, it does not connect to SQL Server. I was expecting that the nanoserver had a SQL Server in it. Am I wrong?
How should I connect this instance to an SQL Server?

I was trying to avoid creating a second Docker instance for the SQL Server. Is this the only way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Here's the auto generated Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerTest2/DockerTest2.csproj", "DockerTest2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerTest2/DockerTest2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerTest2"
RUN dotnet build "DockerTest2.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerTest2.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest2.dll"]
```

Comment: Single-process-per-container is a recommended pattern to use for docker (there are many reasons for that). The better option would be to run another container with Sql Server and configure a network between them (docker-compose could be an option you are looking for). Nanoserver is just a windows and dotnet core.

Comment: Oh I see. I know that's better to use one process per container, but I wanted to test how well/bad it performed on just one. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: I think that is possible. But most likely there would be a need to build up your own image including all necessary dependencies. The perfomance wouldn't be extremely bad, but it would be hard to userstand whether the container is down or not since state of all processed with id != 1 would be ignored. This is used by healthcheck mechanics inside container orchestrators and docker itself.